# On the definition of a subbasis of a topology induced by a system of neighborhood

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, normed-spaces

Consider the following statement:

**Theorem**:
Let $X$ be a vector space and let $\mathcal{P}$ a separating family of seminorms on $X$, that is, given $x_0 \in X \backslash\{0\}$, there exists $p_0 \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $p_0(x_0) > 0$. Define a topology on $X$ by taking, as a local basis $\mathcal{B}$ for the system of neighborhoods at $0$, the sets
$$
V(p,\epsilon) := \{x \in X : p(x) < \epsilon\}, \quad p \in \mathcal{P}, \epsilon > 0,
$$
together with their finite intersections
$$
W(p_1,\dotsc, p_N; \epsilon_1,\dotsc,\epsilon_N) := V(p_1,\epsilon_1) \cap \dotsb \cap V(p_N,\epsilon_N);
$$
and letting a local basis for the system of neighborhoods at each $x \in X$ consist of the translated sets $x + W(p_1,\dotsc, p_N; \epsilon_1,\dotsc,\epsilon_N)$.
With this topology, $X$ is a topological vector space. The seminorms $p \in \mathcal{P}$ are continuous maps of $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

The author of the book says that if $p(x_k - x) \rightarrow 0$, for all $p \in \mathcal{P}$, then the sequence $\{x_k\} \subset X$ converges to $x$ in the topology given by the theorem. I was not able to prove this because I don't how to deal with this topology.

**My attempt** Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. I think somehow we can assume that
$$
U = \bigcap_{i=1}^m (x + V(p_i, \epsilon_i)).
$$
If this is true, I know how to proceed. I think that my confusion is in the questions:

1. How is the subbasis of a topology induced by a system of neighborhood?
2. How is the topology in the theorem?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think so. The context is a little bit different.

Comment: the idea of the proof in the link I gave you works with a few modifications.

Comment: Using that $U = \cap_{i=1}^m (x + V(p_i, \epsilon))$ I know how to use the link you sent. However I don't know if this is true.

Comment: $x+V(p;\epsilon)=\{y: p(y-x)<\varepsilon\}$

Comment: Is it right to say that the topology on $X$ given by the Theorem is $\{ \cup \cap (x_i + V(p_i, \epsilon))\}$ (here union is arbitrary and intersection is finite). ?

Comment: I'm wondering how is explicit the topology given by the Theorem.

Comment: This is the minimal topology that make the semi norms $p$ continuous.

Comment: Finite intersection Ed elements of a sub basis form a basis; arbitrary unions of elements of the basis form the topology.

Comment: Thank you Oliver.